# How to get optgroup labels ID

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a dynamic form. I have Categories which have many entrees and have many sides. When you pick an entree, I'm trying to populate the sides based on the entrees category.

I will make an ajax call in order to populate this but I need the category's ID in order to do this.

I've thought about attaching the category's ID as an ID/Class of the category or even to each option, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's my grouped_collection select:

```
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, restaurant.categories, :entrees, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Attaching data to the DOM

HTML5 introduces "data" attributes - which can be used to attach data to elements on the page:

```js
$('.foo').click(function(){alert($(this).data('id'))})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="foo" data-id="1" >Test</button>
```

With grouped_collection_select you can attach data to the elements by using the `html_options` param.

### Fetching options

There are a few ways to solve this:

**js.erb**

Use Rails as a "lazy mans" [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). This means you would make an AJAX request for something like `/entrees/1/sides.js`.

```
class SidesController

  def index
     @entree = Entree.join(:sides).find(params[:entree_id])
     @sides = @entree.sides

     respond_to do |f|
       f.html 
       f.js
     end
  end
end
```

Which would render a template that looks like this:

```
// app/views/sides.js.erb
jQuery("#some_element").html('<%=j f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, restaurant.categories, :entrees, :name, :id, :name) %>');
```

However this unholy mess of ruby, javascript and HTML kind of sh*ts on all that we have learned about building apps in the last 10 years.

Its hard to debug what is happening where - and even worse its impossible to unit test with javascript testing tools. You have to rely on selenium or capybara which is painfully slow.

**Client side templating**

In this case you would ask your server for JSON and transform it in the client:

lets say `/entrees/1/sides.json` returns an array of objects:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Mashed Potatoe' },
  { id: 22, name: 'Pickled Herring' },
  { id: 51, name: 'Grilled Veggies' }
]
```

You would process this into a list of option elements like so:

```
var promise = $.getJSON('/entrees/1/sides.json');
promise.pipe(function(data){
  return $.map(data, function(item){
     return $("<option>"+ item["name"] +"</option>").val(item[:id]);
  });
}).done(function(opts){
  $('#some_element').append(opts);
});
```

For more complex examples you will want to use a JS templating system.

### Creating custom grouped selects

```
<%= content_tag :select, name: "meal[food_item]" id="meal_food_item"> 
  <%= restaurant.categories.each do |c| %>
    <% uri = category_sides_path(category_id: c, format: :json) %>
    <%= content_tag(:optgroup, label: c.name, "data-uri" => uri) do %>
      <%= options_from_collection_for_select(c.entrees, 'id', 'name') %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Not that `uri` would be wherever you can fetch the sides.

```
$(".new_meal #meal_food_item").on('change', function() {
  var $selected, promise, data_uri;
  $selected = $(this).find(:selected).parents('optgroup');
  promise = $.getJSON($selected.data('uri'));
  promise.done(function(data){
    // update the sides select
  });
});
```

Comment: it's set up so that you would go to /categories/1/sides.json and /categories/1/entrees.json. The sides are associated with the category and not the entree. Here's a quick example https://jsfiddle.net/ky0pkavd/3/ (this works, but only on the first change :( not sure how to get it to work on 2nd change so that's why I've tried the ajax approach)

Comment: Just saw your update @max. The html_options won't work because that applies to the whole collection and not each specific option.

Comment: I would create a partial which outputs the options incase `grouped_collection_select` does not have enough flexibility. The main problem with your fiddle is that it destroys the "data"  that would be needed in the second call. By that I mean the first time you change the option you clean out "#meal_sides", when you change it the second time its just not there.

Comment: You can get around this by cloning and detaching the elements in `#meal_sides` from the DOM and storing them in a var outside the `.change ` callback.

Comment: would you be willing to show me how to do that? I tried yesterday and failed miserably @max

Comment: `var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); $(frag).append($('.whatever').clone());` but I would use ajax.